# Querying for tag values in a given list

Tags: influxdb

Is there any shortform syntax in influxdb to query for membership in a list? I'm thinking of something along the lines of

```
SELECT * FROM some_measurement WHERE some_tag IN ('a', 'b', 'c')
```

For now I can string this together using `OR`ed `=`s, but that seems very inefficient. Any better approaches? I looked through the [language spec](https://influxdb.com/docs/v0.9/query_language/spec.html) and I don't see this as a possibility in the expression productions.

Another option I was thinking was using the regex approach, but that seems like a worse approach to me.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

InfluxDB 0.9 supports regex for tag matching. It's the correct approach although of course regex can be problematic. It's not a performance issue for InfluxDB, and in fact would likely be faster than multiple chained OR statements. There is no support yet for clauses like IN or HAVING.

For example: `SELECT * FROM some_measurement WHERE some_tag =~ /a|b|c/`

Comment: Any suggestion to do it with the timestamps? Related to my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55725829/influxdb-query-by-timestamps-sql-type-in-clause